# Sending push notification to a specific user in cloud function FCM

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

**Please note that this question is not about getting device token on client side.**

I am very new to `react-native` and `firebase` and I want to implement push notication service of FCM. What I am planning to do is to send a notification to particular device using its device token **on my nodejs app server or cloud function( not through console)**. But as I have found, FCM doesn't provides any API to accrss token by username. Suppose I want to send notification to user X( for the time being, suppose that one user signs only on single device). Now using the function `sendToDevice()`, I can send the message to a specific device. But how would I know the device token of user X. Do I need to store tokens in the firebase database by myself? Or can I get along without storing FCM tokens?

Please guide me because firebase docs aren't clear about this.

Answer (score 1):

Save the device token for a particular user in DB and then you can use fcm-node npm in which there is a simple function to send a push to a particular device token.

You also need to use the FCM server key which you will get easily on the firebase console.

Comment: I have 2 simple questions for FCM:1.  I have seen some people using Admin SDK fir pushing FCM notificatiin in nodejs while some do it without using admin SDK. How first is different from second?

Comment: 2. When we talk about an app server, what are we exactly talking about: a cloud function deployed to firebase or a simple nodejs server that we can run on our local machine?

Comment: @VIPULTYAGI 1- You can use as per your convenience, it depends on you, some people don't want to add an extra npm, so they are directly doing it

Comment: Please look at my 2 question above

Comment: If this is the case, don't you think it is a security issue cuzz even people who don't hqve admin SDK can push notifications.

Answer (score 0):

FCM doesn't offer a way to associate device tokens to individual users who might be using your app from multiple devices.  You will need to write code to associate a device token to a user account by sending that token to your backend, along with the user's ID.  Only then can you collect FCM tokens for that user, and message them on any of their devices.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am asking. So it means I need to store the tokens in the database? Doesn't FCM provides any api fo this?

Comment: You have to collect and store tokens on your own.

Comment: Please tell me do I really need to send FCM tokens to app server to store them in database or can I store them in database on client side itself?

Comment: You can do whatever meets the needs of your app.  For FCM messaging, you will need the device tokens on your backend.

Comment: By backend you mean firebase cloud functions??

Comment: Cloud Functions is considered a backend component, yes.